# Debugging read() system call - does not continue executing until CTRL-C is pressed

Tags: c, system-calls

Hi I need to use the system call read() to read from I/O. I have the following code

```
//Reading in the commands
for(;;) {
    n = read( fd, buf, 128 );
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("---\n");
}
```

It will not print the "---" string until I I terminate the program, then it'll print all at once. I've tried flushing the input stream as well with no luck. I'm not very familiar with `read()` so I don't exactly know how it works. The reason I need to use `read()` is because I need to make CTRL-D terminate the program. Would anyone mind enlighten me as to why is this happening and how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

PS: I did some more testing an got an interesting result:

```
for(i;i<3;i++) {
      if( read( fd, buf, 128 ) < 0) {
        printf("Read returned less than 0");
      } else {
          printf("Read is working\n");
      }
  }
```

removing the "\n" character makes it print "Read is working" 3 times after the third input is read. having the character in there will make it print after each input is read.

Comment: Never call `fflush` on `stdin` - it is valid only for output streams -  using it on an input stream results in **Undefined Behaviour**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why it was doing that but `fflush(stdout)` before it loops again solves the problem.

for my orginal code:

```
//Reading in the commands
for(;;) {
    n = read( fd, buf, 128 );
    fflush(stdin);
    [Other statements]
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

solved the problem. Still wondering why this needs to be done.

Comment: Please read above comment regarding `fflush(stdin)` and/or read the man page for `fflush`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of ‘read‘ to detect EOF on STDIN (i.e. pressing Ctrl-D). The code you posted is an infinite loop.

Comment: yes it's suppose to loop infinitely until user presses CTRL-D.

Comment: also read() returns the size it read in. Ctrl-D will return 2, and negative value if an error has occurred. Does it return anything special for EOF?